# one interesting qn related to convergence of integration..

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

let $f_n:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a nonnegative sequence of Borel measurable functions which converge to a function $f,$ and the integral of all $f_n$ and of $f$ are all $1.$ Then does the integral of $|f_n-f|$ goes to 0 as $n \to\infty?$

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing a bit what you meant in my edit. Correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem:-

Let $ \{g_{n}\}$ be a sequence of integrable function which converge almost surely to an integrable function $g$. If $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of functions such that $|f_{n}|\leq g_{n}$ and $\{f_{n}\}$ converges to $f$ almost surely. If $\int_{X}g\,d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}g_{n}\,d\mu$ then $\int_{X}f\,d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}f_{n}\,d\mu$

More generally:-
If $\{f_{n}\}$ is a sequence of integrable functions from a measure space $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu$) and $f_{n}\to f$ almost surely and $f$ is integrable. Then $\int_{X}|f_{n}-f|\,d\mu\to 0$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}|f_{n}|\,d\mu=\int_{X}|f|\,d\mu$.

$|f_{n}-f|\leq |f_{n}|+|f|\,\,,(=g_{n})$(as in the theorem)

and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(|f_{n}|+|f|)\,d\lambda=2\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|\,d\lambda$.

(So $\int_{X}g\,d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}g_{n}\,d\mu$)

And each $f_{n}$ and $f$ are integrable by assumption .

So applying Dominated Convergence Theorem you get that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_{n}-f|\,d\lambda=\int\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_{n}-f|\,d\lambda= \int_{\mathbb{R}}0\,d\lambda=0$.

Comment: Also, you need one function to dominate all $|f_n-f|.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews A dominating sequence of integrable functions for which the limit of integral is integral of limit suffices .

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that geneeral form, and Dominated Convergence Theorem is often taught without that generalization. But why, when you state the General form, do you use variables which make it hard to apply? Here, $f_n$ in the original question becomes $g_n$ in the theorem, and there is another sequence $f_n?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews . I have edited to make it more understandable. Does it seem fine now?